# MySQL ODBC query - CONVERT function

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write an ODBC-standard query to be used across multiple possible ODBC drivers. However when querying a MySQL source, I'm getting some non-standard behavior. I'm hoping there's just a configuration that I'm missing but I fear that MySQL support for ODBC standards is incomplete.

This is the query I'm trying to send, which does not work:

```
SELECT  0 AS GroupColumnID 
,  {fn CONVERT(NULL,SQL_DATE)} AS GroupStartRangeDTS 
,  {fn CONVERT(NULL,SQL_DATE)} AS GroupEndRangeDTS 
, 0 AS FilterColumnID 
, {fn CONVERT(NULL,SQL_DATE)} AS FilterStartRangeDTS 
, {fn CONVERT(NULL,SQL_DATE)} AS FilterEndRangeDTS 
, 5 AS ETLBatchID 
, {fn CONVERT(NULL,SQL_VARCHAR)} AS GroupingFormat 
, {fn CONVERT('Not Defined',SQL_VARCHAR)} AS GroupingField 
, {fn CONVERT(COUNT(*),SQL_BIGINT)} AS TotalRows 
, 71 AS TableID 
, {fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()} AS LastModifiedDTS 
FROM sakila.actor ORDER BY GroupingField, TotalRows
```

If I modify the query to look like this, it does execute on MySQL but does not execute on other ODBC data sources.

```
SELECT  0 AS GroupColumnID 
,  {fn CONVERT(NULL,DATETIME)} AS GroupStartRangeDTS 
,  {fn CONVERT(NULL,DATETIME)} AS GroupEndRangeDTS 
, 0 AS FilterColumnID 
, {fn CONVERT(NULL,DATETIME)} AS FilterStartRangeDTS 
, {fn CONVERT(NULL,DATETIME)} AS FilterEndRangeDTS 
, 5 AS ETLBatchID 
, {fn CONVERT(NULL,CHAR)} AS GroupingFormat 
, {fn CONVERT('Not Defined',CHAR)} AS GroupingField 
, COUNT(*) AS TotalRows 
, 71 AS TableID 
, {fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()} AS LastModifiedDTS 
FROM saklia.actor ORDER BY GroupingField, TotalRows
```

Is this a configuration I'm missing or a known problem with MySql? The docs indicate that it accepts standard SQL datatypes (SQL_DATETIME, SQL_VARCHAR) but when running a query through the driver I get an error on the queries at those points.

I'm running MySQL ODBC Connector 5.3.4 on a windows 64 bit machine. I'm having the same issues from both my development machine and my test server.

Comment: Appears to be a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7882

Comment: It has nothing (or very little) to do with ODBC; even through Workbench, MySQL will not accept those types for the CONVERT function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: @uueerdo I'm probably wrong but it appears {fn convert()} != convert() [source](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_convert)

Comment: UUeerdo - I appreciate the response but I'm using the ODBC escape CONVERT function, not the MySQL built in convert.

Comment: xQbert - Thanks, I did see that while I was googling around but it's a 7 year old bug. I suppose unless I go learning some C and fix it myself I'm out of luck there :/

Comment: @PeterJorgensen yeah but status is still verified not fixed... which makes me think bug still exists.

Comment: @xQbert Nope, I'm mistaken, was not familiar with that notation so I just figured it was little more than standard "sugar" that MySQL basically ignores to comply.... though maybe that actually is the reason there is this issue in the first place.

Comment: How do you mean "does not work"? Does ODBC throw an error or MySQL? If the latter then you can enable the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) on your database and see what it's being passed.

Comment: @miken32 - I'll try that and update with what the general query log shows, however based on the error message I'm getting back the ODBC driver is actually not translating and is instead passing the query as-is to the MySQL engine and expecting it to handle it. I tested this by running SELECT {fn CONVERT(NULL,CHAR)} directly on the mysql command line and that worked, despite being the ODBC version of the query. If my assumption here is off I'll update the post with the general query log.